# How to set function to start when previous end in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, delay

Hi I have this script which has one function which fill text value 
 and another which search this text. It works fine but "searching" function waits only 4 seconds for input. Without delay it doesn't work, because searching will be run without any text. I want to modify it to start function *"document.searchform.submit()"* when previous function ends, so input is filled. It seems simple but I am new in JS. Thanks.

```js
final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);   
var queryTextField = document.getElementById("search_query");  
queryTextField.value = final_transcript; 

//filling input with text
document.getElementById("search_query").value=final_transcript;  

//start searching after 4 seconds
setTimeout(function(){document.searchform.submit();}, 4000);
```

Comment: use deffered, it will helps to make your function wait till other functions completes

Answer (score 0):

You just call the function at the end of your function

```
first_function ()
{
    alert('whatever');
    second_function();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to wait! You can search immediately if the previous value and new value are not same.

```
if(document.getElementById("search_query").value!=final_transcript)
  document.searchform.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Use Jquery as below
$("#search_query").value(final_transcript).promise().done( function() {
document.searchform.submit();
});
```

Comment: final_transcript gets the text, but submit  runs without any value.